# unresolved external symbol D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW

Tags: c++, directx

I am new to DirectX. I have this code:

```
IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(pSurface), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pSurface));
char text[] = "Desktop.bmp";
wchar_t wtext[20];
mbstowcs(wtext, text, strlen(text) + 1);//Plus null
LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(ptr, D3DXIFF_PNG,pSurface,NULL,NULL);
```

These are my included headers:

```
#include <D3dx9tex.h>

#include "pch.h"
#include "Game.h"


extern void ExitGame();

using namespace DirectX; using namespace DirectX::SimpleMath;

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;
```

I keep getting the error IDirect3DSurface9:  undeclared identifier as well with D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Error msgs:
[link to error msgs screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu6qu.png)

**UPDATE**:
I added the missing headers to the Game.h file and the undeclared identifier errors now disappeared but now i get a new error: unresolved external symbol D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW.

[Screenshot to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwhYD.png)

Comment: include <d3d9.h> to fix this issue, there's no need to include d3dx9tex.h if you include <d3dx9.h>

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: ``#include <d3d9.h>`` ``#include <d3dx9.h>`` did you try to that? You should include both headers cause you are using it's extension API too

Comment: Still the same problem. I can go to the Declaration and definition but when I make a build I get these errors.

Comment: Then can you post all the relevant error messages?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you have not included those headers in game.cpp

Comment: This code is from Game.cpp.

Comment: You should link to Direct3D extension library: ``#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9")``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this link to solve the error.

https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/580434-d3dxsavesurfacetofile-error-1120/

Answer (score 1):

`D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW` is a utility function in the deprecated D3DX9 helper library. It's not actually part of Direct3D at all, and is an optional side-by-side component that only ships in the legacy DirectX SDK.

As noted, you need to link with `d3dx9.lib` *AND* have the legacy DirectX SDK installed *AND* have your include/lib paths set up correctly for using the legacy DirectX SDK. It's worth noting that the include/lib path order is quite different if you are using VS 2012 or later which makes use of the Windows 8.x or Windows 10 SDK. The legacy DirectX SDK headers are largely out-of-date.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/), and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

> If you are new to DirectX, don't bother with legacy Direct3D 9. Use DirectX 11. For a starting point, see the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)